# How to get original file path in the script with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

An example code:

```
//in the file app.module.js
module.exports = framework.module("app", [
    require('./api/api.module').name
])

//in the file app/api/api.module.js
module.exports = framework.module("app.api", [
])
```

Here are two dependent modules named 'app' and 'api'.
Module name is always same as file path to the module file (except `module.js` part, e.g. for file at `app/api/api.module.js` module name is 'app.api').

Is it possible to make webpack provide a filename of the included file during compilation, so following can be done?

```
//in the file app.module.js
module.exports = framework.module(__filename, [
    require('./api/api.module').name
])

//in the file app/api/api.module.js
module.exports = framework.module(__filename, [
])
```

Where `__filename` is an actual path to the file folder.

It does not really matter what's format of name of the module, but it should be unique (for framework reasons) and lead to the module location (for debug reasons).

*Update:*
I've solved it for myself - this can be done by custom webpack loader which substitutes a certain placeholder with file path string. But anyway question is still open.

Comment: When you say "Module name is always same as file path to the module file." do you mean the first part of the file name? e.g. "app" in `app.module.js` and "api" in `api.module.js` ? Because the "file path to the module file" is inconsistent between the 2 example modules you provided (i.e. `app.module.js` and `api/api.module.js`)

Comment: @MitchKarajohn Thanks, corrected question. Module name should reflect file path to file where the module is defined. And the question is about how this file path can be injected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you said you resolved this yourself, yet, here's my take on it.

Your solution includes using a custom loader, however, maybe you could have solved it in a different way.

First step, in your `webpack.config` add these in the config object:

```
context: __dirname, //set the context of your app to be the project directory
node: {
    __dirname: true //Allow use of __dirname in modules, based on context
},
```

Then, add this in your list of plugins:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    SEPARATOR: JSON.stringify(path.sep)    
})
```

This will replace all `SEPARATOR` instances in your modules with whatever the correct path separator is, for the system you are working on (you will have to `require('path')` in your `webpack.config` for this to work)

And finally in whatever module you want you can now get its name by doing

```
var moduleName = __dirname.replace(new RegExp(SEPARATOR, 'g'), '.');
```

So, for example

```
//in the file app.module.js
var moduleName = __dirname.replace(new RegExp(SEPARATOR, 'g'), '.');
module.exports = framework.module(moduleName, [
    require('./api/api.module').name
])

//in the file app/api/api.module.js
var moduleName = __dirname.replace(new RegExp(SEPARATOR, 'g'), '.');
module.exports = framework.module(moduleName, [
])
```