# Get the path to the current JS web component

Tags: javascript, relative-path, web-component

I have a JS web component that needs to load in other resources (specifically a `src` for an `iframe` it adds to the DOM, but this would be a problem for any resource with a relative path).

This resource needs to be specified relative to the calling page, which I can get easily enough from `window.location`.

However, the file that it needs to point the `src` at is relative to the JS file that's executing, and as that's a component I can't be sure where it will be.

So:

```
example.com/index.html 
  |__> {unknown path}/web-component.js
  |__> {unknown path}/resource.html <-- I want to get this
```

That component might be in `node_modules` or `bower_components` or `webpackOutput` or wherever, but the DOM it creates needs to point to the same location that it has been served from, not the page that's executing it.

As this code is in a web component [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) is `null` and `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` might not include the component.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js

Comment: @admcfajn Cheers, but that applies to node.js, I'm in a web environment. I could use node.js server side to edit the file to have a hard-coded path, but that's really a last resort.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all for this situation. Great idea below. This one might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410541/how-to-get-original-file-path-in-the-script-with-webpack you're in a web-environment, but you're precompiling with node, correct?

Comment: @admcfajn not myself - this project is a web component, I'm using TS, but I want the output to be usable without a complex build chain (source: https://github.com/EvolutionJobs/html-editor/blob/master/html-editor.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a potential solution, but it has both potential browser compatibility and performance issues.

The idea is `new Error().stack` includes the path to the file executing.

So...

```
// Get stack string
const stack = new Error().stack.split('at');

// Get the last entry
const scriptPath = stack[stack.length - 1].trim();

// The component will share the path up to the last slash
const componentPath = scriptPath.substring(0, scriptPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

It relies on the format of the stack, the contents of the stack, and `new Error()` not causing any performance issues as it loads, so answers with a better method are welcome!